# What Stargate SG-1 episodes have Ben Browder and Claudia Black in them?

Tags: stargate, episode-identification, stargate-sg1

What season or specific episodes did Claudia Black and then Ben Browder appear in *Stargate SG-1*?
I want to buy those seasons but NOT the entire series.

Also, was Ben Browder in all the post-series movies?

Comment: IMDB covers this completely. Did you check http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0112871/ for the list of 40 episodes?

Comment: She's not in all of season 9. If you're buying individual episodes with Vala in, there's quite a few you wouldn't want.

Comment: Farscape fan, eh?

Comment: Yes, I am a fan, I just finished re-watching the series on the blu-ray release.  I am keeping The Peacekeepers War for a special time!!

Comment: ["200"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/200_(Stargate_SG-1)) (episode 10x6) deserves a special mention for [the *Farscape* scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCNDdlCo4rA).

Answer (score 12):

Both Ben Browder and Claudia Black appear **together** in the following episodes of *Stargate SG-1*:

**Avalon: Part 1 (15 July 2005)

Origin (29 July 2005)

The Ties That Bind (5 August 2005)

The Powers That Be (12 August 2005)

Beachhead (19 August 2005)

Crusade (3 March 2006)

Camelot (10 March 2006)

Flesh and Blood (14 July 2006)

Morpheus (21 July 2006)

The Pegasus Project (28 July 2006)

Insiders (4 August 2006)

Uninvited (11 August 2006)

200 (18 August 2006)

Counterstrike (25 August 2006)

Memento Mori (8 September 2006)

Company of Thieves (15 September 2006)

The Quest: Part 1 (22 September 2006)

The Quest: Part 2 (10 January 2007)

Line in the Sand (16 January 2007)

The Road Not Taken (23 January 2007)

The Shroud (30 January 2007)

Bounty (6 February 2007)

Bad Guys (13 February 2007)

Talion (20 February 2007)

Family Ties (27 February 2007)

Dominion (6 March 2007)

Unending (13 March 2007)**

and apart in

**Prometheus Unbound (December 2004)**

**Ex Deus Machina (26 August 2005)

Babylon (9 September 2005)

The Fourth Horseman: Part 1 (16 September 2005)

Prototype (16 September 2005)

The Fourth Horseman: Part 2 (6 January 2006)

Collateral Damage (13 January 2006)

Ripple Effect (20 January 2006)

Stronghold (27 January 2006)

Ethon (3 February 2006)

Off the Grid (10 February 2006)

The Scourge (17 February 2006)

Arthur's Mantle (24 February 2006)**

[image: Ben Browder and Claudia Black - Stargate]

Ben Browder (as Cameron Mitchell) was introduced as a main character and appears in every episode of Season 9 and 10. Claudia Black was introduced as a Special Guest Star in season 8, returns as a 'recurring guest star' in season 9 and appears in every episode of season 10 as a main cast member.

They both appear in the two *Stargate* made-for-TV movies; *The Ark of Truth* and *Continuum*.

Comment: SO if I want everything, SEason 8,9 and 10 does it, Thanks.

Comment: @Craig - She's only in episode 12 of Season Eight; "Prometheus Unbound".